# I want send a filepart image with Vertx, I want replicate this case in code like Postman

Tags: kotlin, vert.x, vertx-httpclient, vert.x-webclient

[PostmanExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EWx9.png)

```
  fun sendFileToMatch(path:String){
    val client = WebClient.create(vertx);
    var form = MultipartForm.create()
      .binaryFileUpload("image","imageName" , path, "image/jpeg")

    client.post(8888, "localhost", "/search?")
      .putHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
      .sendMultipartForm(form) { }
  }
```

when I run the code show bad request I have put exactly key "image" and send filepart image

Comment: Could you please post your code, instead of posting a screenshot of it? That would help debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - your client code seems fine.

The only suspicious part is the `path` itself, as you don't specify how exactly you get it in your code, and the fact that you didn't specify how you handle response from the server: you just do `{}` in your example

Here is a fully working example for you to refer to, though:

```kotlin
        val vertx = Vertx.vertx()

    val router = Router.router(vertx)

    router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
    router.post("/search").handler {
        val uploads: Set<FileUpload> = it.fileUploads()

        uploads.forEach { upload ->
            println(upload.name()) // "image"
            println(upload.fileName()) // "imageName"
            println(upload.size()) // 42537
        }

        it.response().end("OK!")
    }

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router)
            .listen(8888)

    // We read the PNG file from /resources
    val path = object {}.javaClass.getResource("5EWx9.png").path
    val form = MultipartForm.create()
            .binaryFileUpload("image","imageName" , path, "image/png")

    val client = WebClient.create(vertx);
    client.post(8888, "localhost", "/search?")
            .putHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data")
            .sendMultipartForm(form) {
                if (it.succeeded()) {
                    println(it.result().bodyAsString()) // "OK!"
                }
                else {
                    println(it.cause())
                }
            }
```

As the file to upload, I used the [PostmanExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EWx9.png) you've provided, which is a PNG image, which I put in the `/resources` directory of my project.